# Some confusion about express middleware

Tags: express

```
    app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  next();
});
app.get("/admin", (req, res, next) => {
 
  res.send("<h1>Admin page</h1>");
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening on port 3000");
```

why it is not calling the next middleware /admin and gives error Cannot GET /

Comment: What request are you sending to the server?

Comment: i am sending  /get request to server

Comment: app.get("/") doesn't match the request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send your server a request like this:

GET /

then it will hit the `app.get("/", ...)` route handler.  If you put a `console.log("got here")` inside that route handler, you will see it logged.  But, then you call `next()` and do not send any http response so the routing continues.  You only have one other route and that doesn't match `/` so, you end up with the default 404 handler in Express.

If you want your "/" route handler to send a response, then modify it to do so:

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("got top level /");
});
```